# Validate google's ID token in Python is too slow

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am coding with "https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/backend-auth"

token is

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjI2ZmM0Y2QyM2QzODdjYmM0OTBmNjBkYjU0YTk0YTZkZDE2NTM5OTgiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FjY291bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20iLCJhenAiOiIzMjAzMTg3OTI4MTQtcXBnZ2ZscGYxNWhpN3NrbDUzbzR2aXA5cTdhb2QzOWYuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiIzMjAzMTg3OTI4MTQtcXBnZ2ZscGYxNWhpN3NrbDUzbzR2aXA5cTdhb2QzOWYuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiIxMDQwODQzNzYwMjYyNzczNTA0MDgiLCJlbWFpbCI6InVzNDAyNzY5NDExQDE2My5jb20iLCJlbWFpbF92ZXJpZmllZCI6dHJ1ZSwiYXRfaGFzaCI6InlicUhLQlRPVVM5ZWJwS3FHVmZmcFEiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTYxODI0MTksImV4cCI6MTU1NjE4NjAxOX0.ABE-rltHIdEfxHwVHXMpcwg1HdoKarrGEcj2gqRAtegDpjelxdqnQslcA4V7nm_mZx_eqkw54FiWeDJ0Rif39kf-hUuBMJdjD4qOzKLqUbyjLgYTy0qi5zZ4vav95K6Y-LeOGTLOGWNiak9t1a3D1y9Xvub24r0t7dU9chqAp7aZnqW_995si_6oJwlPOQCMkfmhkUm9xeYyAWNRsJN6W2rUN41oFUN8KAboUhyjgQFnOdu85KzeDbll_m-HaFYEHh5FdzUnpgt79wKNtFXPnq000EYtHa4AvhtV9MoidMQCx0g02f1PEw4VvAGsQT6MN6Z4cJH-kGl8LHxZA1dslQ
```

and I can get data from https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=TOKEN
[image]

But when I use Google API Client Library, I found that `id_token.verify_oauth2_token` is too slow to get result.
Why? My code is beyond:

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = '320318792814-qpggflpf15hi7skl53o4vip9q7aod39f.apps.googleusercontent.com'

def auth_google(token):
    CLIENT_ID = GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID
    try:
        # Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
        idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), CLIENT_ID)
        print idinfo
        # Or, if multiple clients access the backend server:
        # idinfo = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request())
        # if idinfo['aud'] not in [CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]:
        #     raise ValueError('Could not verify audience.')

        if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
            raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')

        # If auth request is from a G Suite domain:
        # if idinfo['hd'] != GSUITE_DOMAIN_NAME:
        #     raise ValueError('Wrong hosted domain.')

        # ID token is valid. Get the user's Google Account ID from the decoded token.
        auth_user_id = idinfo['sub']
        print auth_user_id
        return auth_user_id
    except ValueError:
        # Invalid token
        pass
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to fix this issue?

Comment: +0,5s on each token check. unfortunately looks like some kind of cache is required...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how slow Google's API client runs for you. But, it's probbaly because it first fetches Google's auth cert (which is refereshed once a day-ish). Basically it's slow due to a network call rather than heavy code.

Either way, try not to verify the token yourself, it's easy to get things wrong with JWT. Take a look at `google-auth` on pypi, they provide easy authentication helpers.

Comment: @chendind Were you able to find the solution to this problem? Surprisingly it's slow for me only on apache servers. Except on apache it works faster. Please let me know if you were able to find the solution.